# Navigate to a page n times

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am creating a Windows 8 App with C#. In a form the user has to enter the number of teams that want to play, once chosen the number, I should show to them the same page for each team where they can put the name of each player and the name of each team. How can I call this page n times, one for each team?

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow is a bit unclear. I assume you have a `Page` with some kind of "next" button that navigates to the same page but for the next team?

You can use the navigation parameter for this.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(TeamPage), parameter);
```

Just create a class for your navigation parameter, that contains all necessary information such as current team number and max team number.

You can get the navigation parameter like this:

```
protected override sealed void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = e.Parameter as MyType;
}
```

Or like this if you use the `LayoutAwarePage`:

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    var parameter = navigationParameter as MyType;
}
```